# Pandas matplotlib boxplot with mean trendline

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I'd like to add a trendline to my boxplot showing the mean values. Anyone figured it out using pandas?

My code goes like that:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = df.boxplot(column='val', by='DATE',ax=ax)
```

And I get a nice boxplot as a result.

[image]

Now how can I add a line to connect the mean values?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you generate such line, simply connecting the mean values with straight lines? Some interpolation?

Comment: Can you attach a link to the data?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to plot the means? If so you can pass `showmeans = True` to the boxplot, and it will use a marker to show the (arithmetic) mean. My personal opinion is that this will look better than a line superimposed on the boxplot (which is also possible to do):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date_id': np.tile(pd.date_range('2018-10-01', '2018-10-5').astype(str), 10),
        'value': np.random.randn(50)
    }
)

data.boxplot(column = 'value', by = 'date_id', showmeans = True)
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but yes I’d like to connect these markers, i.e a line surimposed on the boxplot. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Connecting the means can be achieved by adding the `meanline = True` argument. See also [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) of `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`.